# DeleteDuplicates and select which one to delete from a pair

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

In this case if two lists with the same total then one list is deleted.
Can I add one more condition to choose which one to be deleted, for example the deleted list between the two is the one where sum of the first three elements of the list is larger than 0?

```
   list = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
    0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}};
    DeleteDuplicates[list, Total[#1] == Total[#2] &]
```

**EDIT:** This is the whole problem actually I'm trying to solve. I have `tup1` and I removed some elements to get `tup2` like below. However, now I want to add one more condition for which one to deleted from the pair. The `list1` from the pair is deleted if `Total[#1[[1 ;; 3]]]< Total[#2[[1 ;; 3]]]` .

```
tup1 = Tuples@{{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0,
      1}, {-1, 0, 1}};
tup2 = DeleteDuplicates[
   tup1, (#1[[1 ;; 3]] == #2[[4 ;; 6]]) && (#1[[4 ;; 6]] == #2[[1 ;; 
           3]]) || (#1 == -#2) &];
```

Comment: `chooseTheRightOne /@ GatherBy[list, Total]`?

Comment: chooseTheRightOne? what do you mean by that?

Comment: the function that, given a list of lists, each with the same total, chooses the one you want

Comment: Would it be able to modify by adding condition for `DeleteDuplicates` because I have a code needs to use that?

Comment: I would not use `DeleteDuplicates` for this.

Comment: I actually need to add condition to choose between two elements so I need to use `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: @anhnha `DeleteDuplicates` simply won't do what you want it to. I see that you have further requirements you did not include in the question. It would be helpful if we had thte whole picture before attempting to answer. Could you please spell out the whole problem then?

Comment: OK, I'll edit it.

Comment: @MarcoB updated

Comment: @anhnha Thank you for the update. Unfortunately, `DeleteDuplicates` only removes identical elements, under some condition. It does not have a mechanism to make further choices on which element to delete, so it is not the appropriate approach for your problem. You can still use it to obtain `tup2` (although answers to your previous question suggested much faster approaches for that too), but then you will have to further work on `tup2`, for example in the way I showed below, to get the final result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**  You can use your test function with  [`Gather`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Gather.html) to group the elements of your input list:

```
gathered = Gather[tup1, (#1[[1 ;; 3]] == #2[[4 ;; 6]]) && (#1[[4 ;; 6]] == #2[[1 ;; 3]])
   || (#1 == -#2) &];
```

Now, you can select a *representative* for each group using your desired criterion:

```
tup3 = Map[First @* MaximalBy[Total @* (Take[#, 3] &)]] @ gathered;
```

Compare sums of first three columns in `tup3` versus `tup2`:

```
And @@ NonNegative[Total[tup3[[All, ;; 3]], {2}] - Total[tup2[[All, ;; 3]], {2}]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

FWIW, an alternative way to construct your `tup1` and `tup2` that makes it easier to select from *duplicates*:

First, construct a list of 2X3 lists:

```
tup1B =  Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, {2, 3}];
Flatten /@ tup1B == tup1
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Alternatively, you can construct `tup1B` from your `tup1` using `tup1B = Partition[#, 3] & /@ tup1;`.

Defining input list this way makes application of your test functions more straightforward:

```
tup2B = DeleteDuplicates[tup1B, # == Reverse[#2] || (#1 == -#2) &];
```

When `Flatten`ed, `tup2B` is same as your `tup2`:

```
Flatten /@ tup2B == tup2
```

We can use the same test function to group input list elements:

```
gatheredB = Gather[tup1B, # == Reverse[#2] || (#1 == -#2) &];
```

If we take the first elements from each group and `Flatten` them we get `tup2` again:

```
Flatten /@ First /@ gatheredB == tup2
```

Select representatives from groups using your desired criterion:

```
tup3B = Map[Flatten @* First @* MaximalBy[Total @* First]] @ gatheredB;
```

Compare the totals of first 3 columns in `tup3B` versus `tup2`:

```
And @@ NonNegative[Total[tup3B[[All, ;; 3]], {2}] - Total[tup2[[All, ;; 3]], {2}]]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

**Original answer:**

You can also use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) and use the third argument to *reduce* the groups:

```
gb = GroupBy[list, Total, First @* MaximalBy[Total[Take[#, 3]] &]]
```

> ```
> <|1 -> {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 3 -> {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 4 -> {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}|>
> ```

```
Values @ gb
```

> ```
> {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I'll need to play with them for a while.

Answer (score 6):

The second criterion you mentioned (i.e. positive sum of first three elements) is not sufficient to break all ties in your list, once grouped by `Total`. Instead, in the following I first gather the sub-lists into groups by their total, then in each group I select the one with the highest sum of the first three elements.

```
First@*TakeLargestBy[Total[#[[;; 3]]] &, 1] /@
 GatherBy[list, Total]

(* Out: {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Using DeleteDuplicates**

You can sort the input list by the sum of first 3 columns before using `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
DeleteDuplicates[ReverseSortBy[Total[Take[#, 3]] &] @ list, Total[#1] == Total[#2] &]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

Applying this to `tup1`:

```
tup2sorted = DeleteDuplicates[SortBy[-Total[Take[#, 3]] &]@ tup1, 
 (#1[[1 ;; 3]] == #2[[4 ;; 6]]) && (#1[[4 ;; 6]] == #2[[1 ;; 3]]) || (#1 == -#2)&];
```

To verify that the first 3 column sums of undeleted elements are greater-or-equal than those of their deleted counterparts we can use `Gather` as follows:

```
And @@ Map[GreaterEqual @@ (Total /@ #[[All, ;; 3]]) &]@
  Select[Length@# > 1 &]@ Gather[SortBy[-Total[Take[#, 3]] &]@ tup1, 
   (#1[[1 ;; 3]] == #2[[4 ;; 6]]) && (#1[[4 ;; 6]] == #2[[1 ;; 3]]) || (#1 == -#2)&]
```

> ```
>   True
> ```

**Note: Why does this work?**

Take a simpler example to see how `DeleteDuplicates` work:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Range[4], Abs[#2 - #] == 1 &]
```

> ```
> {1, 3}
> ```

`DeleteDuplicates` applies the test function to 2-subsets of the the input list

```
Subsets[Range@4, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}
> ```

and skips testing on 2-subsets whose first element is already deleted as can be seen from the `Trace` output below:

```
Trace[DeleteDuplicates[Range[4], Abs[#2 - #] == 1 &]] // Rest // 
    Rest // Column
```

[image]

So if we sort the input list in desired order, `DeleteDuplicates` will eliminate elements that come later in the sorted list as duplicate:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Reverse @ Range[4], Abs[#2 - #] == 1 &]
```

> ```
> {4, 2}
> ```

`Gather` works the same way:

```
Gather[Range[4], Abs[#2 - #] == 1 &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
> ```

```
Trace[Gather[Range[4], Abs[#2 - #] == 1 &]] // Rest // Rest // Column
```

[image]

```
Gather[Reverse@Range[4], Abs[#2 - #] == 1 &]
```

> ```
> {{4, 3}, {2, 1}}
> ```